# Issue with Updating Section Capacity in WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, validation, sql-update, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm working on a WordPress plugin and I'm trying to add a feature that allows users to update the section capacity of a class section. However, I'm encountering a problem where the updates fail to save properly. Here's the relevant code I'm using.

```
function mj_smgt_edit_section()
{
    $model = $_REQUEST['model'];
    $cat_id = $_REQUEST['cat_id'];
    $retrieved_data = mj_smgt_single_section($cat_id);

    ?>
    <div class="form-body user_form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 width_70 margin_right_10px_res">
                <div class="form-group input">
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-control" style=" display: flex; gap: 12px; ">
                        <input type="text" style="width:50%"  name="section_name" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $retrieved_data->section_name; ?>" id="section_name">
                        <input type="number" style="width:50%"  name="sectioncapacity" maxlength="3" value="<?php echo $retrieved_data->class_capacity; ?>" id="sectioncapacity">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                const inputField = document.getElementById('sectioncapacity');

                inputField.addEventListener('input', () => {
                console.log('Value changed:', inputField.value);
                });
            </script>
            <div class="row col-md-2 margin_top_10px_web padding_left_0_res width_30 margin_top_13px_res" id="<?php echo $retrieved_data->id; ?>">
                <div class="col-md-6 width_50_res padding_left_0">
                    <a class="btn-cat-update-cancel" model="<?php echo $model; ?>" href="#" id="<?php echo $retrieved_data->id; ?>"><img src="<?php echo SMS_PLUGIN_URL."/assets/images/listpage_icon/cencal.png"; ?>" alt=""></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 edit_btn_padding_left_25px_res width_50_res padding_left_0">
                    <a class="btn-cat-update" model="<?php echo $model; ?>" href="#" id="<?php echo $retrieved_data->id; ?>"><img src="<?php echo SMS_PLUGIN_URL."/assets/images/listpage_icon/save.png"; ?>" alt="">   </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    die();
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I update the section capacity and save the changes, the capacity is not getting updated properly. Even though I can see the updated capacity value in the WordPress database is always 0, when I try to retrieve the data again, it's displaying as 0. Additionally, if I make any edits to the Wordpress database value, it reverts back proper value.

I've tried sanitizing and converting the input to integers using intval(), but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Could anyone please review the code and suggest any changes or potential solutions to ensure that the updated section capacity is saved and displayed correctly? Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: All the code you posted seems perfectly fine. The problem is somewhere else in the code. How do you save the data?

Comment: I appreciate your response. I managed to address the problem by reviewing the JS files. The error originated from the JS button file, where allowing the data to be saved caused the issue.